# How to authenticate websites that use my web service

Tags: php, web-services, authentication

To simplifying the issue, suppose, I have a PHP web service that displays my server's current datetime and this service output its data in any mean, plain text, JSON object, etc. I have a list of websites that only should able to use this service while any other websites should not to have access to this service.

The question is: How could PHP on my server able to distinguish the request from www.allowed-website.com and then give it the access and forbid the access to www.anyother-website.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to implement signed requests with a private key, this way you dont need to pre-authenticate, credentials are not sent over the wire, and most importantly, its not possible to do a man in the middle attack, an attacker can only resend the exact request.

Both the server and the client knows the private key, its then used to validate and sign the requests.

```
<?php
$public_key = hash('sha256', 'Client identification, call it public key.');
$private_key = hash('sha256', 'A secret only the server and client know');

/**
 * Packet for POST request
 */
$packet = http_build_query(array(
    'do' => 'foo',
    'body' => 'bar'
));

/**
 * Sign the packet with private key - which returns valid request token
 */
$token = hash_hmac('sha256', $packet, $private_key);


/**
 * Build the x-headers, with public key and request token
 */
$header = array(
    'X-Public: ' . $public_key,
    'X-Token: ' . $token
);

//..do curl request with headers
?>
```

Then on server side you parse the x-headers, lookup the client based on the public key, then re-hash_hmac the request with the private key, and if it matches the token then the request is authenticated.

```
<?php

//or do a lookput on your API clients table ;p based on the public key
$public_key = hash('sha256', 'Client identification, call it public key.');
$private_key = hash('sha256', 'A secret only the server and client know');

$packet = http_build_query(array(
    'do' => $_POST['do'],
    'body' => $_POST['body']
));

if (hash_hmac('sha256', $packet, $private_key) == $headers['X-Token']){
    //valid request
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vast subject. You have many options, which might include:

- asking the calling server to include credentials (a user id and a password/secret key, or just a user id if it's non-trivial)
- asking the calling server to include credentials (some user id) and a signature
- filtering by IP address
- using SSL client certificates

You might want to get a look at how existing web services perform authentication/authorization. Many (Facebook, Google+, Twitter, etc.) use OAuth. Others (Amazon for instance) use signatures. I'm too lazy to think about any others right now :-)